# How to solve this recurrence $K(n)=2K(n-1)-K(n-2)+C$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

The recurrence is $K(n)=2K(n-1)-K(n-2)+C$ where $C$ is a constant.
What I have tried is substituting $2K(n-1)$ as we do in fibonnacical recurrences. It didn't gave me a fruitful expression! 
Can someone help in solving it? 
Not a homework problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
K(n+1) \\ K(n)
\end{bmatrix}=A
\begin{bmatrix}
K(n) \\ K(n-1)
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
C \\ 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$

where

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Therefore,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
K(n+1) \\ K(n)
\end{bmatrix}=A^n
\begin{bmatrix}
K(1) \\ K(0)
\end{bmatrix}+
\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}A^k+I\right)
\begin{bmatrix}
C \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$
K(n)=nK(1)-(n-1)K(0)+\frac{1}{2}Cn(n-1)
$$

by noticing that

$$
A^k=
\begin{bmatrix}
k+1 & -k \\ k & k-1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 10):

#### The other answers are way too complicated for this particular problem.

They're useful in more general cases, but they're completely overkill here.

\begin{align*}
K(n) &= 2 K(n - 1) - K(n - 2) + C  \\
K(n) - K(n - 1) &= K(n - 1) - K(n - 2) + C
\end{align*}

Just *look at this equation for a few seconds*.
It's *literally telling you* that the difference between successive elements increases by $C$ every step.
So... just go ahead and count how many times you add $C$ to the difference $K(1) - K(0)$:

$$K(n) = K(0) + \sum_{k=1}^{n} K(1) - K(0) + (k - 1) C$$

Notice you don't need any linear algebra, eigenvectors, or other higher-level math for this problem. It's just algebraic manipulation.

I'll leave the last step of simplifying the summation to you.

### Edit:

or I'll just do it for you myself, since you seem to think it leads to another recurrence...

\begin{align*}
K(n) &= K(0) + n(K(1) - K(0)) + C\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k-1)  \\
&= K(0) + n(K(1) - K(0)) + C \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: indeed Beautiful !

Comment: Thanks! I'll admit that it wasn't obvious to me -- at first I was trying to be "creative" by turning this into a continuous equation, via converting differences into derivatives and seeing if I knew the solution to the (delay-?)differential equation. But as soon as I subtracted $K(n-1)$ from both sides to turn the differences into derivatives, I saw there was a much easier way to solve this, hence this answer. :)

Comment: When you're used to these things, you can often solve problems in the "complicated" way more quickly than you can spot simplifications.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Yeah that's true. It's just that I hate giving nonconstructive answers (the kinds where you already have to know what the solution looks like in order to find it) because they're totally underwhelming and unenlightening. Eigenvalues and linear algebra seemed like the wrong approach -- they didn't use deductive reasoning, they just pulled the form of the solution out of a hat, which I hate doing because it doesn't teach anyone anything. It just tells the OP that he needs to already know the answer.

Comment: @Mehrdad, your "just algebraic manipulation" leads to linear answer; but it's not correct, solution is quadratic.

Comment: Yeah you are right I will just accept the correct solution! Actually this solution leads us to another recurrence ! The expression is correct but isn't solved yet!

Comment: @MichaelGaluza: Dude, my solution **is** quadratic...

Comment: @Mehrdad, use force of parentheses

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: Michael is totally wrong, but do you really need me to do the last step for you? No, this shouldn't lead you to another recurrence. It just simplifies to $K(0) + n(K(1) - K(0)) - n + C\sum_{k=1}^{n} k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k$ is just $n(n+1)/2$. This *is* the right answer to your question.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza: No, I'm not going to use parentheses, because this expression is completely unambiguous without them. How about you read the expression correctly instead?

Comment: @Mehrdad, *completely unambigous*, do you say? Surely you are joking. Anyway, MSE is not a forum.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza: Yeah, and I'm surely serious. How did *you* manage to read it?

Comment: Can you suggest me some books to read solving recurrence problems? I haven't solved recurrences in my course yet but I do encounter them in online contests etc.! @Mehrdad

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: Unfortunately I don't know, I'm not really an expert on them either.

Comment: Okie what i figured out as I only glanced your solution was that you need to express the way you had written in the second line and take a summation ! That leads to a recurrence.. Later on that statement where you start from bottom rather than top leads to correct solution! I too believe in less concepts more application

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: I don't quite understand what you mean by starting from the "bottom" vs. the "top"... but the summation I had shouldn't have led to a recurrence -- the first two terms are constants, so you can pull them out of the sum and multiply them by $n$, and for the last term can factor out $C$ and then just sum from $0$ to $n-1$ over $k$. Summing over $k$ is pretty easy, even if you don't know how to do it... it's just triangle, so it's half the square plus half a diagonal. You shouldn't get a recurrence anywhere.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: I just realized, you might want to look up the phrase *linear constant-coefficient difference equation*.

Answer (score 6):

To keep things general, suppose $k_0=A$ and $k_1=B$.  Then the next few terms are:
$$k_2=2A-B+C\\
k_3=4A-3B+3C\\
k_4=6A-5B+6C\\
k_5=8A-7B+10C\\
k_6=10A-9B+15C$$

The pattern seems to be (for $n\ge2$) that 2 more $A$'s are added, 2 more $B$'s are subtracted, and $n-1$ more $C$'s are added,
$$k_n=(2n-2)A-(2n-3)B+\frac{(n-1)(n)}{2}C$$

A proof by strong induction along with some messy algebra will give you your answer

Answer (score 4):

Here is more standard way. Rewrite your equation:
$$
K(n)-2K(n-1)+K(n-2)=C \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
Solution of this is $K=K_0+K_{part}$, where
$$
K_0(n)-2K_0(n-1)+K_0(n-2)=0\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
and $K_{part}$ is any solution of $\eqref{1}$.

Now we're finding solution of homogenuous equation $\eqref{2}$ in a form $K(n)=\mathrm{const}\cdot \lambda^n$ and get
$$\lambda^{n}-2\lambda^{n-1}+\lambda^{n-2}=0\Longrightarrow \lambda^2-2\lambda+1=0;$$
$\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$, and
$$
K_0(n)=A+Bn.\tag{3}\label{3}
$$

$K_{part}$ we'll find in a form $K_{part}=\alpha n^2$ (polynom of degree $0$ and $1$ we used yet). Substitute it in $\eqref{1}$ and get $2\alpha=C$.

So, solution is
$$
K(n)=A+Bn+\frac{Cn^2}{2}.
$$

If you prefer, we can take $K(0)=A$ and $K(1)=A+B+C/2$; hence,
$$
K(n)=K_0+(K_1-K_0)n+\frac{Cn(n-1)}{2}
$$

Comment: might be nice to explain how you just came up with the form $c \lambda^n$, because it looks pretty magical to someone who doesn't already know that's the right thing to do.

Comment: @Mehrdad, I can say just "it works". But, if you want perfect rigor, read whatever contains "recurrence relation".